# Is this the correct way of working on an ML problem?

Tags: self-study, classification, python, scikit-learn, model-comparison

I am working on an assignment where I have been provided a data-set using which I have to do the following:

A. The data in the F20 column is missing, I have to use various imputation strategies and then compare the results.

B. I have to compare performance of decision tree vs any other two classification techniques for which I am using Naive Bayes and SVM.

I have adopted the following strategy to build and evaluate the model:

1.impute Nan in the F20 row

2.balance the classes using SMOTE method

3.using min-max scaler to normalize data between 0 and 1

4.divide the data set into training and testing 80/20

5.use the training data to grid search best parameters with stratified k fold

6.obtain the grid_search._best_score i.e cross validation mean accuracy as a     performance metric to compare with other models.

7.also obtain the best_params and set it to fit the model again on complete      training data using the best parameters

8.then predict class y_pred using the model for input x_test from testing data set and get the classification report (y_pred, y_test) with accuracy, mean, precision, recall, kappa, etc on the testing data-set.

I am mostly wondering about the correctness of steps 6, 7 and 8. Is this the correct way of comparing ML models with each other?

Kindly look at my dataset CE802_Ass_2019_Data.csv and my notebook CE802 - CLASSIFICATION COMPARATIVE STUDY.ipynb which can be found [here](https://github.com/rohan260696/ML-Assignment.git), so that I can be assured I haven't committed any grave sins and would satisfactorily submit this assignment.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated. I'd suggest you take the [site tour](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already and have a look at the [asking part of the help section](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

Comment: You're asking about 6, 7, 8, but it's important to note that 2, 3, and 4 cannot be done in that order. You cannot take actions that mutilates the testing dataset like class balancing, or using it to learn data transformation parameters. The correct sequence would be 4, then 3, 2 using the training data set to learn the transformation parameters only, and not applying any balancing to the testing set.

Comment: @MatthewDrury Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @MatthewDrury But am I correct in my evaluation of the model? I am confused between using the mean cross validation accuracy obtained from best_score of grid search and accuracy obtained from testing data in order compare my models with each other

Comment: @Rohan make sure you also check the guidelines for asking [self-study] questions: https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: The question seems pretty on-topic to me, it could use some formatting for improved clarity though...